# Pandas ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, importerror

Whenever I try to `import pandas as pd` it shows the error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'window' from 'pandas.core' (//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/__init__.py)

Comment: Please add the whole stack trace

Comment: How have you installed pandas? Please consider adding more details to the question.

Comment: Try `pip install pandas` in terminal and retry importing pandas